# i can't install app-debug.apk at my phone

Tags: android, adb

i try to build android app that can fatch data from wordpress website, but when i build the app-debug.apk and install it into my phone it cant be installed.

Libraries Used in this project

```
loopj async http

Swipe Back Helper

Square Picasso image loading
```

Comment: Libraries don't matter... Does it install in an emulator? Do you get any errors? Is your phone detected by your computer or IDE?

Comment: i don't run it in emulator, i derecly sent it into my phone

Comment: Please check the `minSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file and whether they are compatible with your device's Android version

Comment: yes its compatable with my device, i build it to my device